# Find number of terms in the GP series makes 3280

Tags: javascript

A GP is given, 1+3+3^2+3^3....+3^(n-1). We need to find the term that make the sum equal to 3280.

I am trying to so it in this way:

```
var s, a, r, n;

a = 1;
r = 3;
n = 0;

do {
    s = (a * ((Math.pow(r, n)) - 1)) / (r - 1);
    n++;
    console.log(s);
} while (s == 3280);

console.log(n);
```

But the answer is not coming. What am I doing wrong and how to solve this?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var s, a, r, n, ans;

a = 1;
r = 3;
n = 0;

do {
  n++;
  s = (a * (Math.pow(r, n) - 1)) / (r - 1);
  console.log('s = ' + s);
  if (s == 3280) {
    ans = n;
    break;
  }
} while (s <= 3280);

console.log('n = ' + n);
console.log('answer = ' + ans);
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

For a start,

```
do { 
    xyz; 
}
while (s == 3280);
```

performs the action inside the do block once and then repeats it as long as the condition inside the while block is satisfied. Since in your case it is not satisfied after one iteration, it stops immediately.

Replace the condition with "s <= 3280" and then see what you need to do to get the expected result.